# Laravel Query Builder to Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following PHP code:

```
$users = DB::table('users');

if (Input::has('minAge') && Input::has('maxAge')) {
    $users = $users->whereBetween('age', array(Input::get('minAge'), Input::get('maxAge')));
} else if (Input::has('minAge')) {
    $users = $users->where('age', '>=', Input::get('minAge'));
} else if (Input::has('maxAge')) {
    $users = $users->where('age', '>=', Input::get('maxAge'));
}

if (Input::has('sex') && Input::get('sex') !== "0") {
    $users = $users->where('sex', '=', Input::get('sex'));
}

$users = $users->paginate(15);

return View::make('search.result', compact('users'));
```

However I would like to retrieve through Eloquent as the entity object has some functionality needed in view.

Anyway, I've tried to mimic the above but it doesn't work, I think the objects are rather overriden than chained.

Here is my attempt:

```
if (Input::has('minAge') && Input::has('maxAge')) {
            $users = User::whereBetween('age', array(Input::get('minAge'), Input::get('maxAge')));

} else if (Input::has('minAge')) {
            $users = User::where('age', '>=', Input::get('minAge'));

} else if (Input::has('maxAge')) {
            $users = User::where('age', '>=', Input::get('maxAge'));
}

if (Input::has('sex') && Input::get('sex') !== "0") {
            $users = User::where('sex', '=', Input::get('sex'));
}

$users = User::paginate(15);

return View::make('search.result', compact('users'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```php
$input = Input::only('minAge', 'maxAge', 'sex');

$query = User::query();

if (! is_null($input['minAge'])) {
    $query->where('age', '>=', $input['minAge']);
}

if (! is_null($input['maxAge'])) {
    $query->where('age', '<=', $input['maxAge']);
}

if (! is_null($input['sex'])) && $input['sex'] !== "0") {
    $query->where('sex', '=', $input['sex']);
}

$users = $query->paginate(15);

return View::make('search.result', compact('users'));
```